# Android animate + move a layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to move a LinearLayout half out of screen on click of a button in the layout, and when the button is clicked on the half moved out layout it returns back to its orginal position.

I know it can be done simply by using translate layout and moving x position of the layout from 0% to -50%, and doing the reverse.

The problem I face is :

- Although the layout is drawn half out it is not actually moved ie the layout is drawn out but the co-ordinates (for taking in clicks) of its children are not moved accordingly to the new position.

Is there any way to move the layout properties along. I want the that when the button which is initially clicked to move it half out is clicked for the second time slides the layout back.

Comment: Try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html - For older Android APIs: http://nineoldandroids.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a go:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setLeftMargin(int value) {
    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myLinearLayout.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = value;
    myLinearLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

Usage:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "leftMargin",
            0, -1 * halfWidth).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).start();
```

and

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "leftMargin",
            -1 * halfWidth, 0).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).start();
```

Read @damian's comment for animation libraries.